# Python PyPDF2 merger doesn't let os.remove work

Tags: python, pypdf

I can't figure out how to close the files I'm trying to delete in python. Code:

```
merger = PdfFileMerger()
for auth in newAuths:
    merger.append(auth)
merger.write(r"C:\stack\overflow.pdf")
for i in newAuths:
    os.remove(i)
```

Everything works until the last two lines of code. It returns: 'PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:'
Curious how I can close merger from accessing a file?

Comment: Have you tried calling `merger.close()` before iterating over the files to remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is still open and being used by the `merger` the [close()](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileMerger.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger.close) method of `PdfFileMerger()` will close the file and allow you to remove it.

```
merger = PdfFileMerger()
for auth in newAuths:
    merger.append(auth)
merger.write(r"C:\stack\overflow.pdf")
merger.close()
for i in newAuths:
    os.remove(i)
```