# Delete Directory which fails because of opend PDF file

Tags: python, pdf, shutil, pypdf

Hey guys I'm new here,

**Program explanation:** I'm currently working on a python program that unzips folders which include PDFs to an "temp" folder. It then splits the pages of the PDFs to single page PDFs and sorts them into folders on another path ("/Georeferenzieren/0; /Georeferenzieren/1; ...) depending on the page number.
For this specific part of the code I followed [this guys](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/split-pdf-files-in-python) tutorial.

**Problem:** That all works perfectly fine, but when I try to delete the temp folder, an error is displayed that the first file of the folder is still being used by another process.

(ger)

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird: 'e:\Intern\Programmieren\Python for Work\Testumgebung\temp\20220524_0109_V01_Auskunft_01_A3_H.pdf'

(en)

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'e:\Intern\Programmieren\Python for Work\Testumgebung\temp\20220524_0109_V01_Auskunft_01_A3_H.pdf'

**What I tried:**

1. Restarting PC to make sure no program uses the PDF. I think the error still occured because the PDF is opend by the python file.
2. adding `pdf.close()` (pls see code below)
3. adding `Pdf.merger.close()`, like [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68640396/19485340) suggested, which didn't work since I'm not using the merger. (pls see code below)

**Code:**

```
#variables from the code befor this passage
run = 0
tempPath = "E:\Intern\Programmieren\Python for Work\Testumgebung\temp"
geoPath = "E:\Intern\Programmieren\Python for Work\Testumgebung\Georeferenzieren"

#splitting up PDFs to singel Page PDFs
#https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/split-pdf-files-in-python
print("###Split up PDFs")

file2pages = {
    0: [0,1], 1: [1,2], 2: [2,3], 3: [3,4], 4: [4,5],
}

for root, directories, file in os.walk(tempPath):
    for file in file:
        run = run + 1
        filePath = os.path.join(tempPath, file)
        pdf = Pdf.open(filePath)
        newPdfFiles = [Pdf.new() for i in file2pages]
        newPdfIndex = 0

        for n, page in enumerate(pdf.pages):
            if n in list(range(*file2pages[newPdfIndex])):
                newPdfFiles[newPdfIndex].pages.append(page)
            else:
                # make a unique filename based on original file name plus the index
                pdfPath = os.path.join(geoPath, str(newPdfIndex), file)
                outputFilename = f"{pdfPath}-{newPdfIndex}.pdf"

                # save the PDF file
                newPdfFiles[newPdfIndex].save(outputFilename)

                newPdfIndex += 1
                # add the `n` page to the `newPdfIndex` file
                newPdfFiles[newPdfIndex].pages.append(page)

        #save last PDF file
        pdfPath = os.path.join(geoPath, str(newPdfIndex), file)
        outputFilename = f"{pdfPath}-{newPdfIndex}.pdf"
        newPdfFiles[newPdfIndex].save(os.path.join(geoPath, "1. Page", outputFilename))
        print(f"Splitting up the {run}. PDF.")

        #pdf.close()
        #Pdf.merger.close()

#deleting temp folder
print(end = "\n")
print("#Removing temp folder...")
shutil.rmtree(tempPath)
time.sleep(2)
```

**Question:** I would like to know if there is a way to close the used PDF before deleting the folder

Comment: Check for running processes related to python in task manager and terminate them. That should resolve the error. I know you restarted the PC but the processes might've started again post restart.

Comment: Do you know a way to find programs related to python via task manager? Python itself is not running and I couldn't find a good solution yet ...

Comment: Can you try using `with` block at `Pdf.open`  step?

Comment: Always open files inside a `with` statement. Handle other, similar resources in that way, too. That said, take a look at the `pathlib` module, which can simplify quite some of your code.

Comment: "Pdf.open(filePath)" - PDF is not defined. Please add your input statements

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a clean code that does the same. Tested on my machine.

```
import os
import shutil
import time
from pathlib import Path

from pikepdf import Pdf

# assuming team and geo are present in your project dir
temp_path = Path(".").joinpath("temp")
geo_path = Path(".").joinpath("geo")

# splitting up PDFs to singel Page PDFs
# https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/split-pdf-files-in-python
print("###Split up PDFs\n")

for root, directories, files in os.walk(temp_path):
    for file in files:
        file_path = temp_path.joinpath(file)
        print(f'processing file {file_path}')

        # HERE
        with Pdf.open(file_path) as pdf:
            file2pages = {i: [i, i+1] for i in range(len(pdf.pages))}
            for pdf_index, pages_range in file2pages.items():
                new_pdf = Pdf.new()
                [new_pdf.pages.append(pdf.pages[i]) for i in range(*pages_range)]
                output_path = geo_path.joinpath(str(pdf_index))
                output_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
                out_filename = output_path.joinpath(f'{file}-{pdf_index}.pdf')
                print(f'saving {pages_range[0] + 1}-{pages_range[1]} pages as {out_filename}')
                new_pdf.save(out_filename)

# deleting temp folder
print()
print("#Removing temp folder...")
shutil.rmtree(temp_path)
time.sleep(2)
```

Your code seems to have numerous issues. Hence re-implemented it. Observe the usage of `with`

if you still get error, you might want to check the file permissions on your machine.

**EDIT:** Based on the requirement to convert each page of the pdf into a separate pdf, updated the code to work with pdfs having variable number of pages.

Comment: Thanks for the approach but that didn't do the job. I'm still getting the same error.
But its not the newPdfFiles that are the problem I think since the error is pointed at the first whole PDF (not the split up ones).

fyi: I tried "pdf.close()" again with no success

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include the `with` block at `Pdf.open`

Comment: I tried replicating the code including `with` block and it just worked fine.

Comment: @duxt4r__ pls check now. I have edited the entire answer

Comment: @duxt3r__ Please check now. Added the dynamic dictionary creation based on number of pages